# Connect to MySQL local database via PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, apache, ubuntu

I have two servers running on Ubuntu. Server 1 only has MySQL installed and acts as an database. Server 2 is a Apache web server. The database is internal and so as the Apache server and they can ping each other but the database server is not accessible via the internet. I can telnet into the database server from the Apache but I can not connect to the database via PHPMyAdmin.

So the question is how I can configure this to work. I also don't want to allow access to the whole server (databases), access only via user name and password specified.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Define your user as `user@[hostip-of-Php-myadmin-server]` and you should be set?

Comment: it's already assigned, I can connect inside the tunnel via mysql e.g. mysql -h IP -u USER -p

Comment: I also tried changing the if (empty($dbserver)) $dbserver = 'localhost';

Comment: Can you post your mysql and Apache configuration?

Answer (score 0):

It was a BIND issue, it's all fixed now.